# PayPal REST API Authorise Payment PHP

Tags: php, ios, rest, cordova, paypal

I've been searching the web for a solution to this or just some decent documentation but I am at a loss.

I am trying to authorise payments made from an app using Paypal Cordova SDK which is similar to PayPal IOS SDK.

I have a server running PHP 5.4 and I have installed using composer the PayPal REST API SDK onto my server. I need some help or a small sample script to show me how to authorise a payment made to my server (For such a big company PayPal's documentation is really hard to navigate, search or use.).

My other question is where do I put the link to authorise payments (IP/authorise.php). Do I attach it to my developer portal on PayPal some how?

Many Thanks